# Load Alexnet weights into keras model using theano backend

Tags: python-2.7, keras, theano, pre-trained-model

I am using a pre-trained model such as Alexnet, In this case also, ending up with the same error.

I was downloaded the alexnet_weights from here-->https://github.com/heuritech/convnets-keras

then I tried like this

from keras.models import load_model

base_model=load_model('alexnet_weights.h5')

I ended up with

ValueError: No model found in config file.

please help me to get rid out of it.

Answer (score 0):

AlexNet is not a supported default model in [Keras](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16).  Maybe you could try with VGG16 first:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

features = model.predict(x)
```

Then you could move to using AlexNet, but you will need to build the model structure first and store that as "base_model" in your case.  You only have the weight file I believe.  Then you can load the weight file you have.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I already did with VGG-16. which is default model in keras. But, In the case of Alexnet( not default in keras), I am trying to load - "alexnet_weights.h5." it's is throwing an error

Comment: can I have a further suggestion

Comment: You have to build the Alexnet model.  For example, if the VGG-16 has 16 layers, and the AlexNet has more than 17 layers, where will those extra ones go?  It is like trying to pour a 1L of water into a .25L cup.  It won't work correctly!